# What is an efficient way to send large data over the wire?

Tags: c#

I have a list of strings `List<string>`. Actually is a list of file paths. And I need to send it to a webservice.  The list can contain huge count of items (1 000 - 10 000).

What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this? considering that the message payload will be quite high.

I am asking for ideas and principles, not code samples.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For paths - firstly (or rather: lastly) gzip or deflate it. If large numbers of things are going to have common roots, nest that data perhaps?

i.e. so

```
/foo/bar/blap/a/b
/foo/bar/blap/c/d
```

becomes

```
/foo/bar/blap
 /a/b
 /c/d
```

Beyond that - the payload is going to far exceed any protocol overheads etc, so use whichever protocols etc make life simple for you.

Comment: +1 That's a nice idea. Do you happen to know (by chance) a lib that will transform a list of paths this way automatically?

Comment: But I'd guess the gain over just zipping it won't be large. The main advantage would be a compact in memory representation.

Answer (score 1):

just using compression. gzip or deflate stream. string compression ratio is very good.

Answer (score 0):

if you are stuck with a certain communication protocol, perhaps chuncking can be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization combined with deflation techniques already suggested is highly efficient and reliable.